# Div que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla restante

Tags: css

Quiero hacer que un div ocupe hasta abajo del todo dela pantalla.

Yo como solución pensé en declarar a dicho div (en el ejemplo "div2") con `height:100%;`.

Al no funcionarme, vi que la gente dice que la solución a esto es declarar `html, body {height=100%;}`.

Sigue sin funcionarme como se muestra en snippet de abajo.

Otra cosa que he probado es declarando `height:100vh;`. Pero esto es incorrecto, ya que al tener el "div1" esto provoca que haya un overflow y yo simplemente quiero que rellene la pantalla.

```css
html, body{
  height:100%
  margin 0;
}
#div1{
  height:80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#div2{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"> Contenido del div 1 </div>

<div id="div2"> Contenido del div 2. Este div quiero que ocupe hasta el final de la pantalla de manera vertical. </div>
```

¡Salud!

Comment: Agregale una position: fixed; a la clase #div2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante `javascript`, con su propiedad `screen.heigth`, la cual toma el alto total de la pantalla en la que te encuentras y se la agregas mediante una variable. Quedaria algo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

      var height = $(window).height();

      $('#div2').height(height);
});

</script>
```

Asi tomara la altura de cualquier pantalla en la cual se visualice tu pagina o aplicacion

Answer (score 4):

coloca el `display:flex` en tu body y agrega el `flex-direction:column` para tomar el 100% del largo de forma vertical

Ademas tenias un error de sintaxis en el height y margin en el selector html,body

De la siguiente manera, es el resultado que esperas

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#div1{
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#div2{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[mira aqui el ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ukwocuob/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Para lograr el efecto deseado puedes declararle al body como `display: flex` y que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla además de decirle que su dirección sea de columna `flex-direction: column`, al div que quieres que ocupe el resto de espacio declaramos `flex: 1` que es equivalente a `flex-grow: 1`

```css
html, body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100vh;
  margin 0;
}
#div1{
  height:80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#div2{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"> Contenido del div 1 </div>

<div id="div2"> Contenido del div 2. Este div quiero que ocupe hasta el final de la pantalla de manera vertical. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu contenedor *main* agrégale un `min-height 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

1. para `div` `width` Se establece en 100vw, `Div` height Establecer como
   100vh(La siguiente es una breve descripción de vw y vh).
2. Después de eso, si quieres aplica un Reset.

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh; 
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Agrégale a la clase `#div2` `position: fixed;` esto deberia de funcionar, si algo me cuentas.

Comment: Como puse en el post eso no sirve... Esto genera que el div tenga el tamaño de la pantalla, pero al ya haber otro div, este div es demasiado grande.

Comment: @CarlosMilles me dices si esto te sirve.

Comment: Esa solución no sirve amigo