# Div que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla en Angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap, typescript, div

Estoy usando bootstrap, tengo un div tipo row con dos columnas. Quiero que este div ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla del navegador, de modo que no se vea ninguno de los elementos inferiores mientras no se haga scroll.

He probado la solución del enlace [Div que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla restante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150822/div-que-ocupe-todo-el-alto-de-la-pantalla-restante) , traduciéndola a typescript pero no consigo que funcione.

Esto es lo que he puesto en el module.ts del componente, habiendo añadido antes window como provider en el app.module.ts:

```
 constructor(private window: Window) { }

  @ViewChild('frontcover')
  frontcover!: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var height = this.window.innerHeight;
    this.frontcover.nativeElement.innerHTML.offsetHeight = height;
  }
```

Comment: Saludos @Paula, para el alto podrías probar simplemente con `heigth: 100vh;` utilizándolo en el *div* que necesitas. Si esto no funciona, tal vez podrías agregar el *html* que tienes para ver como tienes tu estructura. ;)

Comment: Gracias, @Israel-ICM !